# how printf() function behaves in printf("%d %d %d",a,a=a+5,a);?

Tags: c, printf

i think, the codesample in c given below  should output: 10,15,10. But it gives output: 15,15,15. my question is how this result comes?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a=10;
    printf("%d %d %d",a,a=a+5,a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you are in the realm of undefined behaviour.

The C standard does not say in what order arguments are evaluated.

So on one compiler the right 'a' might be evaluated first, then `a=a+5` and then the first will be 15.

Then you'll get 15, 15, 10.

Another compiler will evaluate the other way around.

Then you'll get 10, 15, 15

Comment: And yet another compiler may give 42, 42, 42. And yet another compiler may give you a program crash. When code has undefined bahavior it makes no sense to reason about about specific result.

Comment: The order of evaluation of function arguments is _unspecified behavior_. Meaning deterministic & can be reasoned about. However, a side effect on an object which appears unsequenced in relation to another side effect of value computation of that same object is _undefined behavior_ - and that is far less meaningful to reason about. The OP's code has both unspecified behavior and undefined behavior at once.